# Questions regarding MySQL and PDO Persisent Connection

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have been running some tests with PDO Persistent connection, and it seems as if every time I run a script, it opens up a new connection regardless...

I check it by using the show process list, and reloading the page with the same credentials.
It looks like a new process is made while the previous ones are at sleep command.

So what is the idea here? What exactly is persistent?

Comment: Check the second answer in the linked question. It's 3rd link from my google search BTW.

Comment: That did not answer my question really.

Comment: "Remember - there's no guarantee that a user's HTTP requests will be serviced by the SAME apache child/mysql connection" - this is the answer

Comment: I see. I couldn't make sense of it until you focused me on that.